# continious hover on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I have two neighbouring elements `$("#video")` and `$("#progress")`.

I would like a third element `$("#time")` to be shown using `fadeIn` when the mouse enters either one of these elements, and hidden again using `fadeOut` when the mouse leaves the element. I can get this to work, but there is a small issue.

Whenever the mouse enters one of either elements, coming out of the other, the `$("#time")` element first gets hidden and than shown again, while I would like it to be shown always.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZ44R/) demonstrates the issue more clearly.

How can this be fixed?

Note that the elements, although close to each other in the webpage, are actually pretty separated in the code, so it is not possible to put them all together in one big div and put the hover on that div.

Comment: Have you thought about adding both of the elements into a containing div and setting the hover on that div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout method for your Fade Out code and with a variable find out that if you should hide that or not.

```
var ShouldBeShown = false;    
$(".hover").hover(fIN, function(){
  ShouldBeShown = false;
  setTimeout(fOUT, 50);
});
function fIN() {
  ShouldBeShown = true;
  $("#time").fadeIn(300);
}
function fOUT() {
  if(!ShouldBeShown)
    $("#time").fadeOut(300);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EyFdn/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap those two elements with another div

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id="video" style="background: green; height: 100px;" class="hover">VIDEO</div>
  <div id="progress" style="background:red" class="hover">bar</div>
</div>
<div id="time" style="display: none">01:35</div>
```

then bind the hover to the wrapping div

```
$("#wrapper").hover(function () {
  $("#time").fadeIn(300);
}, function () {
  $("#time").fadeOut(300);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/mEppj/)

Comment: I like your solution, but it would cause undesired results if the `divs` had different widths. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/mEppj/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late on this one, but I wanted to say that I would check to see if the elements were being hovered over and execute the fadeout if they are not. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/nZ44R/5/). I also would add the `stop()` method to avoid multiple animations firing if the user enters and exists the `div` quickly.

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
  $('#time').stop(true,true).fadeIn(300);
},function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if($('.hover:hover').length == 0){
        $('#time').stop(true,true).fadeOut(300);
    }
  },0);
});
```

Comment: +1 good answer.. curious as to why you have the setTimeout though

Comment: @wirey If you don't `setTimeout()` then the `mouseleave event` is fired before the `hover` state changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing a div around the entire block and adding the hover class to it

```
<div class="hover">
    <div id="video" style="background: green; height: 100px;"> VIDEO </div>
    <div id="progress" style="background:red"> bar </div>

    <div id="time" style="display: none"> 01:35 </div>
</div>
```